# Rails, form is calling wrong action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, routes, actioncontroller

I have made my form:

```
      <tbody>
        <% @player.bases.each do |basis| %>
        <td><%= basis.id %></td>
        <td><%= image_tag(basis.image_url(:thumb), class: 'thumbnail') %></td>
        <td><%= link_to basis.name, basis %></td>
        <td><%= basis.cost %></td>
        <td><%= basis.short_info %></td>
        <td>
            <%= form_for @player, url: {:controller => 'players', :action => :remove_detail} do |f| %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :type, :value => 'basis' %>
              <%= f.hidden_field :detail_id, :value => basis.id %>
              <%= f.submit 'Remove',class: 'btn btn-danger' %>
            <% end %>
        </td>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

In my routes, I have added this:

```
resources :players do
 collection do
   get 'search'
   post 'remove_detail'
 end
end
```

I have `remove_detail` in my `players_controller.rb`, and I have added this action to `before_action` to get current player. However when I press on my Remove button, it throws me error and tries to run `update` action of my controller. Why?

My `before_action`:

```
before_action :set_player, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :remove_detail]
```

My `remove_detail`:

```
def remove_detail
type = params['type']
id = params['detail_id']

if type == 'basis'
  basis = Basis.find(id)
  name = basis.name
  @player.bases.delete(basis)

end

redirect_to @player, notice: "#{name} detail is removed"

end
```

Comment: Would you mind posting whole your template? And if the one provided is a partial, could you add a template rendering that partial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix that, try as follows:

First of all, I'd redefine your routes as follows:

```
resources :players do
  member do
    delete 'remove_detail'
  end

  collection do
    get 'search'
  end
end
```

This will generate proper url for deleting a `detail` for a "single `Player`":

```
/players/:id/remove_detail
```

Because of REST-y nature of Rails, we defined the url to be accessible by performing `delete` request.

Your form change accordingly:

```
<%= form_for @player, { url: { action: "remove_detail" }, method: :delete } do |f| %>
```

Changing your routes to use `delete` method is more to keep the convention of Rails. `Post` would make your application work too, but - its just Rails-y way.

Good luck!

Comment: Now it throws me an error and tries ot launch `destroy` action of my controller

Comment: @Mr.D, you are right - I've put the code from my head and made a mistake - check updated snippet for `form_for`. Sorry for confusion!

Comment: That worked well. Thank you. One question, why did you make in routes separate member? Can I just add it to my collection? Do I need to create spearate members for each new action?

Comment: Glad you're asking! When defining route for `collection`, it generates url like: `/players/remove_detail`, but because your action is meant to modify a particular single instance of resource (`Player` in your case), preferred way of declaring such route is as for `member`, which effects with url like `/players/:id/remove_detail`. On the other hand, your "search" action doesn't really belong to any particular user and operates on `collection` of `Players`, so registering it in `collection` is preferred way. Check more here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions